# Allow link clicking inside return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, click

http://jsfiddle.net/UsKHa/

I've a div with `return false`.

How do I make a link inside this div clickable?

Especially without removing `return false`, because it's very specific to the plugin I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you added this small function, it would work:

```
$('a').on("click", function(){
   window.location.href = this.href; 
});
```

This will work for any anchor that you return false (or prevent default) for.

Updated fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/UsKHa/1/)

Comment: FYI OP, just because of jsfiddle embeded code in iframe, to test it and see it works use the 'show' page: http://jsfiddle.net/UsKHa/1/show

Comment: this won't work for a link with preventDefault() - if link has it, then window.location.href should not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.some a').click(function(event){
       alert('clicked on link');
  });
```

This triggers the click event for a link **inside your div**

Answer (score 0):

You could set up another `.click` which refers to the link.

```
$('a').click(function(){ window.location.href = this.href };
```

See the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UsKHa/6/)**

Comment: Do you really need two clicks ?

Comment: the other solutions have two clicks as well. don't know if its an elegant way, just saying it works!

Comment: This would bind the click event for the link every time the div is clicked. That doesn't seem right.